# error: 'srandom' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, zxing

I'm building zxing using MinGW, but it fails with these errors:

```
build\core\tests\src\common\BitArrayTest.cpp: In static member function 'static void zxing::BitArrayTest::fillRandom(zxing::BitArray&, zxing::BitArray&)':
build\core\tests\src\common\BitArrayTest.cpp:99:39: error: 'srandom' was not declared in this scope
build\core\tests\src\common\BitArrayTest.cpp:101:15: error: 'random' was not declared in this scope
scons: *** [build\core\tests\src\common\BitArrayTest.o] Error 1
```

I tried adding `-DANN_NO_RANDOM` to the compiler flags, but it didn't help.

Comment: Do you mean [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/) and [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/)?

Comment: No, the code of zxing really uses [srandom and random](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_srandom.htm).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`srandom` is a `linux` function, instead use [srand](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) and if you don't want to change the code from external library, just add `-Dsrandom=srand -Drandom=rand` to the compiler flags.

Comment: It's actually specified in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/srandom.html), which means all UNIX or UNIX-like environments should have it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `<stdlib.h>` header file.